# Make Ghidra recognize thread-local variables

Tags: ghidra, thread

I am trying to reverse an ELF binary that makes use of thread-local variables. I can't figure out how to make Ghidra display them in a friendlier way (something like declaring a struct or similar).

For example, this is how a call to scanf with a FILE* stored in TLS looks like:

```
scanf(*(FILE **)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0xfffffff0),"%d",&num);
```

Ideally, I would like this to look something like:

```
scanf(tls->outfile, "%d", &num);
```

Is it possible to make it more user-friendly? I looked around but I haven't seen anyone complaining about this.

Here's an example code:

```
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

thread_local int foo = 0;

int main(void) {
    assert(scanf("%d", &foo) == 1);
    printf("foo is: %d\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

`tls.c` compile with `CFLAGS="-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -O0 -ggdb -Werror" make tls`

And here's the decompiled code:

[image: Ghidra's decompiler output for tls binary]

Comment: [Okay, so it _does_ indeed handle it differently at `-O0`](https://godbolt.org/z/Gfeda38E9) (and even at `-O3` for that matter) to `static` or a mere global variable. However, what's shown as `in_FS_OFFSET` presumably is `fs:0` and [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33827186) how and why -4 is needed here. Given your answer, I think however, you're conflating things a bit.

Comment: In my answer, they propose a way to support having pointers to the middle of a struct, enabling having negative offsets.
If that were supported, you could retype `in_FS_OFFSET` as a pointer to the end of your struct, and then it would automatically recognize your thread_local fields.

Comment: yes you could do that. However, just like when you see access to the TEB or PEB via one of the selectors on Windows, _this_ is a particular "well-known construct" particular to Linux that should be handled (and is, evidently handled, given the name it is assigned) accordingly. That doesn't make this a struct, however. I really don't see it as of yet.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like this feature is [not yet implemented in Ghidra](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/573).

Comment: What does this have to do with thread-local variables? All I can see in the defect report is that there is no way to properly access structs from a linked list, where the linked list members have an `LIST_ENTRY` as their member. This is a common scheme in NT and support for `CONTAINING_RECORD` therefore a sensible request. But where is the connection to thread-local variables?

Comment: The question is about supporting pointers to the middle of a struct, it has nothing to do with lists. In this case, if you define a struct that would be "thread_local_vars", and get your pointer to the end of it, you should be able to get Ghidra to recognize it, right?